# `Unresolved reference: runBlocking` in android instrumented tests, yet the code compiles just fine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my setup method I have the following code:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    repo = ToDoRepository()

    loadKoinModules(module {
        single(override = true) { repo }
    })

    runBlocking { items.forEach { repo.save(it) } } // unresolved reference
}
```

I get a compiler warning that `runBlocking` is an unresolved reference, even though I have the appropriate import statement: `import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking` as well as the appropriate dependency in my apps `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
  // <other dependecies>
  testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1"
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
}
```

I thought that maybe the solution was to add `androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.2'`. But when I do that my code no longer compiles (yet the warning is gone), what could be the problem here? Is this just a bug in Android Studio?

Some things I already tried:

- Invalidate cache & restart
- Deleting the libraries in the projects `.idea/libraries` folder and syncing the project with the gradle files.

Comment: Yeah, I see that too, in Android Studio 3.5.3. I have been assuming it's an IDE bug.